# Join three tables and update values to particular table

Tags: db2

**TableA:**

```
ID    RES_ID   NAME          
--------------------
1       3     (null)    
2       1     (null)    
3       3     (null)
```

**TableB:**

```
RES_ID    AREA_NAME          
-------------------
3           India        
1           Japan        
3           India
```

**TableC:**

```
AREA_NAME    CITY_NAME          
-----------------------
India        Delhi        
Japan        Tokyo        
England      London
```

I want to join the above three tables and update the CITY_NAME in TableC to NAME in TableA using **DB2**.

Please help me to sort it out.

I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```
MERGE INTO TableA A
USING TableB B, TableC C 
   ON A.RES_ID= B.RES_ID
   AND B.AREA_NAME = C.AREA_NAME
WHEN MATCHED
   THEN UPDATE SET A.NAME = C.CITY_NAME;
```

It displays error message.I want the output as follows,

**Updated TableA:**

```
ID    RES_ID   NAME          
--------------------
1       3     Delhi        
2       1     Tokyo    
3       3     Delhi
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
update A set name = c.name from tableA A 
    inner join tableB B  ON A.RES_ID= B.RES_ID
    inner join tableC C on B.AREA_NAME = C.AREA_NAME
```

The MERGE operator is used to update records when the disired record exists otherwise insert the record. But you already have the record, you only need to update a field. Hence you need an update query

Comment: I have more duplicate values in the field. I want to know should use DISTINCT?

Comment: You have multiple record in tableC with the same area_name? If so, the table_a.name will have any of these values. You can't predict which one... But you don't need a distinct

Comment: If it works, accept the answer so other people with the same problem can use this